# MongoDB logging

Tags: perl, mongodb, logging

I am building a logging system that will log requests and responses to a web service which is distributed across multiple application nodes. I was thinking of using MongoDB as the repository and logging in real-time, or more realistically dumping logs to DB after x number of requests. The application is designed to be considerably high volume and is built in Perl. Does anyone have any experience doing this? Recommendations? Or is this a no-no?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen at lot of companies are using MongoDB to store logs. Its schema-freeness is really flexible for application logs, at which schema tends to change time-to-time. Also, its [Capped Collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) feature is really useful because it automatically purges old data to keep the data fit into the memory.

People aggregates the logs by normal Grouping or [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce), but it's not that fast. Especially MongoDB's MapReduce only works within a single thread and its JavaScript execution overhead is huge. [New aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) could solve this problem.

Another concern is high write through put. Although MongoDB's insert is fire-and-forget style by default, calling a lot of insert command causes a heavy write lock contention. This could affect the application performance, and prevent the readers to aggregate / filter the stored logs.

One solution might be using the log collector framework such as [Fluentd](http://fluentd.org/), [Logstash](http://logstash.net/), or [Flume](http://flume.apache.org/). These daemons are supposed to be launched at every application nodes, and takes the logs from app processes.

[image: fluentd plus mongodb]

They buffer the logs and asynchronously writes out the data to other systems like MongoDB / PostgreSQL / etc. The write is done by batches, so it's a lot more efficient than writing directly from apps. This link describes how to put the logs into Fluentd from Perl program.

- [Fluentd: Data Import from Perl Applications](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/perl)

Answer (score 2):

I use it in several applications through [Log::Dispatch::MongoDB](https://metacpan.org/module/Log%3a%3aDispatch%3a%3aMongoDB); works like a charm!

```
# Declaration
use Log::Dispatch;
use Log::Dispatch::MongoDB;
use Log::Dispatch::Screen;
use Moose;

has log => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Log::Dispatch', default => sub { Log::Dispatch->new }, lazy => 1)

...

# Configuration
$self->log->add(
    Log::Dispatch::Screen->new(
        min_level   => 'debug',
        name        => 'screen',
        newline     => 1,
    )
);
$self->log->add(
    Log::Dispatch::MongoDB->new(
        collection  => MongoDB::Connection->new(
            host    => $self->config->mongodb
        )->saveme->log,
        min_level   => 'debug',
        name        => 'crawler',
    )
);

...

# The logging facility
$self->log->log(
    level   => 'info',
    message => 'Crawler finished',
    info    => {
        origin  => $self->origin,
        country => $self->country,
        counter => $self->counter,
        start   => $self->start,
        finish  => time,
    }
);
```

And here is a sample record from the [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50c453421329307e4f000007"),
    "info" : {
            "country" : "sa",
            "finish" : NumberLong(1355043650),
            "origin" : "onedayonly_sa",
            "counter" : NumberLong(2),
            "start" : NumberLong(1355043646)
    },
    "level" : "info",
    "name" : "crawler",
    "message" : "Crawler finished"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this on a webapp that runs on two app servers. Writes in mongodb are non-blocking by default (the java driver just gets the request for you and returns back immediately, I assume it's the same for perl, but you better check) which is perfect for this use case since you don't want your users to wait for a log to be recorded.

The downside of this is that in certain failure scenarios you might lose some logs (your app fails before mongo gets the data for example).

Comment: Great. Are you doing real time logging? How load intensive is your logging server?

Answer (score 0):

For some interesting ideas for your app, I recommend checking out [Graylog2](http://graylog2.org/about) if you haven't already. They use a combination of MongoDB and Elasticsearch quite effectively. Adding a powerful search engine into the mix can give you some interesting query and analysis options.

For your reference, here's an [Elasticsearch page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2012/05/19/elasticsearch-for-logging.html) dedicated to log processing tools and techniques.

If you are planning to queue the log entries before processing (which I would recommend), I suggest [Kestrel](https://github.com/robey/kestrel) as a solid message queue option. This is what Gaug.es uses, and I've been putting it through it's paces lately. A Java app, it's extremely fast and atomic, and it conveniently speaks the Memcache protocol. It's a great way to scale horizontally, and the memory cache is backed up to a journalled file for a good balance of speed and durability.